# nodejs ftp client with proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, ftp

I am using package promise-ftp to connect ftp. But now I need to connect to this ftp using proxy. Like in FileZilla I have set generic proxy to connect. But I do not know how to do it with this.

promise-ftp is only one ftp client which I found that is using promises. For SFTP I am using ssh2-sftp-client package and there I am able to use proxy via socket. Do you know about some solution please? Or another package which can handle proxy and promises

Comment: Could you find a solution yet?

Comment: any solution, it's 2019?